# exception after magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

After installing Magento 2 with sample data I'm getting below error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Default website is not defined {
"exception":"[object] (DomainException(code: 0): Default website
             is not defined at magento2\\vendor\\magento\\module-store\\Model\\WebsiteRepository.php:144)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your phpmyadmin, open the table `store_website` and manual edit at least one website to default (`is_default = 1`).

Comment: already tried but didn't work